# Selecting a string of a specific length in one-line bash regex

Tags: bash, glob

Sorry for the simple question, but I am new to writing bash programs.

I am trying to write this line:

```
for i in /etc/file*; do SOME-COMMAND $i; done
```

However, I need to make sure that file* can only have 2 characters after file.. Ie, "fileaa" is ok, but "fileabc" is not ok. What changes to my command would I need to make?

Thanks!

Comment: See: [What are the differences between glob-style pattern and regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23702202/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

try changing `*` with `??` as follows.

```
for i in /etc/file??; do SOME-COMMAND $i; done
```

`*` is a greedy wild character which means it will go to match everything, on other side wild character `?` means any single character, so you wanted any of 2 so `??` should help here.