# Get content of wildcard/asterisk

Tags: bash

Is it possible to get the last content of a wildcard?

Let's say I have a list of files:

```
foo-15.csv
foo-32.csv
foo-65.csv
```

etc.

Is it possible to access the wildcard content when using:

```
for file in foo-*.csv; do
    echo wildcard_content
done
```

So that it prints

```
 15
 32
 65
```

**note:** I don't want to use string manipulation with `$file`. The above is a mere example and the globular expression could be anything. Is it possible to access the wildcard content? Is the wildcard content stored in a bash-defined variable that I can call, or something like that?

Comment: While you are asking for the information in asterisk, it is clear that you are interested in the filename without the extension (hence the duplicate). If you are really interested in the matching of wildcards, I suggest to rewrite the glob as a regex and use the `=~` test operator in combination with `BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: @kvantour I am not interested in the duplicate you indicated. The filename part is just an example. And  what is a "glob" ?

Comment: A globular expression is what you call a wildcard. It is different from a regular expression. So if I understand you correctly, if you have a file `foobar.5` which is matched with 'f*b?r.[0-9]'  you would like to be able to know that `*` is matching `oo`, `?` is matching `a` and `[0-9]` is matching `2`?

Comment: @kvantour Oh, ok, thanks. Yes, exactly. I was wondering if those values where stored somewhere, and accessible directly... I never saw that so I suppose it's impossible?

Comment: It is not impossible, it is just not straightforward.

Comment: So your question is, is there an internal list from which `file` gets assigned on each iteration, which you can access?

Comment: @tripleee Not using `file`. Is there an internal variable to which values are assigned each time I call `*`, and can I access it?

Comment: There is no "each time", the glob gets expanded before the loop starts executing, while the command is parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are after is something which resembles `BASH_REMATCH`.

> An additional binary operator, `=~`, is available, with the
>   same precedence as `==` and `!=`.  When it is used, the string
>   to the right of the operator is considered an **extended
>   regular expression** and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).
>   The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1
>   otherwise.  If the regular expression is syntactical
>   incorrect, the conditional expression's return value is 2.  If
>   the shell option `nocasematch` is enabled, the match is performed
>   without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.  Any part
>   of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a
>   string.  **Substrings matched by parenthesized subexpressions
>   within the regular expression are saved in the array variable
>   `BASH_REMATCH`.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index 0 is
>   the portion of the string matching the entire regular
>   expression.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index `n` is
>   the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized
>   subexpression.**

Unfortunately, glob patterns and regular expressions are not
the same (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202), and [this linuxjournal article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globbing-and-regex-so-similar-so-different)). Nonetheless, we can make a one-to-one translation:

```
|-------+-------+---------------------------------------|
| glob  | regex | remark                                |
|-------+-------+---------------------------------------|
| *     | [^/]* | filenames don't have a /              |
| **/   | .*/   | ** repreensts full paths (end with /) |
| ?     | [^/]  | filenames don't have a /              |
| [...] | [...] | the character groups are the same     |
|-------+-------+---------------------------------------|
```

You have to be careful though, as some characters have special meanings in regular expressions, but not in globular expressions. (Eg. `.`, `+`):

So in the example of the OP, you can do this:

```
for file in foo-*.csv; do
   [[ "${file}" =~ foo-([^/]*)[.]csv ]]
   echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

Or a more complicated example:

```
for file in *-substring-[0-3a-9]-foo?.file
     [[ "${file}" =~ ([^/]*)-substring-([0-3a-9])-foo(.)[.]file ]]
     echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

Comment: This sort of reverse engineers what the glob did, but if this is what the OP is trying to ask, I guess there is no more straightforward way (and the answer to "is there an internal data structure" is, emphatically, no).

Comment: @tripleee I agree. There is probably a perl way to do it cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for file in *.csv; do
    echo "${file%.csv}"
done
```

You can remove the `.csv` part like above.

You can understand the working of `%` from the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

It states:

> ${parameter%word} 
>   ${parameter%%word} 
>   The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

@Sorin explained why to use `shopt -s nullglob` in comments. For further explanation, refer to the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

Comment: Note: if the there is no *.csv file in the directory, you will end up listing all the files in that directory. Look into nullglob opt

Answer (score -2):

Similar to @Mihir answer but if you want to access the entire list of files per iteration then

```
files=(*.csv)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo ${files[@]//.csv/}
done
```

Comment: There is no need to do an `ls`. Let bash take care of the globing, it will not screw it up.

Comment: @kvantour - If you just do `files=*.csv` it will not glob and store the*.csv as the value to the variable. Apparent when you do the string replacement. Obviously if you just `echo $files` it will print the files as it is doing the glob then.

Comment: @kvantour actually, in this case ls is beneficial if there is no *.csv in that directory. But as a general rule, ls should not be used for getting file names.

Comment: It would be better to do `files=( *.csv )`, and then do `for file in "${files[@]}"`

Comment: @kvantour - Answer updated following your suggestion, thank you

Comment: As in the other answer: `files=( *.csv)` will result in an array with only one element '*.csv' and then fail if no *.csv files are present. Also `${files[@]//.csv/}` should be `${file//.csv/}` since you want to access the for variable not the entire array.

Comment: @sorin - Please read the explaination of my answer - From the OPs question it isnt clear if he wants the entire list of files per iteration, or just the filename of the current iteration, this is how my answer differs from the others given