# how to remove trailing characters with bash regex

Tags: string, bash, glob

In bash I have the following code:

```
a='and/or fox-----'
a=${a//[\/\_ ]/-}
a=${a//-+$/ }
echo $a
```

With the 3rd line I want to replace the trailing '-' with an empty string, and I know in some contexts the `+$` means "one or more at the end of the string". However, the result I'm getting is `and-or-fox-----`. Does anyone know how to get `a` to be `and-or-fox`?

Comment: These expansion substitutions don't use regular expressions, they use wildcard (or "glob") patterns, which are [just similar enough to be confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-pattern-and-regular-expression)

Comment: Why did you delete your previous post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70917837/using-and-in-bash-regex-and-replacing-spaces-empty-strings

Comment: @LéaGris I just thought this question worded my issue a bit more clearly

Answer (score 2):

You can enable bash  [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) (if not already enabled) and use it with a shell [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

a='and-or-fox-----'
echo "${a%%*(-)}"
```

output:

```
and-or-fox
```

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the hyphens first:

```
a='and/or fox-----'
a=${a//-/}
echo $a
a=${a//[\/\_ ]/-}
echo $a
```

This yields `and-or-fox`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace with Bash's replace variable expansion and extract with Bash Regex all within same statement:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a='and/or fox-----'

# Extracting with bash regex
[[ ${a//[\/\_]/-} =~ (.*[^-]) ]] || :
a=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

printf %s\\n "$a"
```

Comment: sorry what does the part after the =~ on the 6th line do?

Comment: @SaboBoz `=~` is the way to use **regex** in bash, while what you use in your code is called **glob**. The regex here means: capture everything up to the last _non-dash_ character