# unix regex: loop through folder and save files under new name

Tags: bash, loops, unix

I have a folder containing files of the pattern shown below. The plan is to loop through every file name, and match everything between the last / and the . which would match the species name plus underscore in between. But I cannot seem to figure out the right regex.
After the match works, I would like to save the file under a new name, where _sort is appended to the original file name.

The files to loop through

```
/home/directory/escherichia_coli.spart
/home/directory/pseudomonas_aeruginosa.spart
/home/directory/pseudomonas_fluorescens.spart
/home/directory/streptocuccus_agalactiae.spart
```

My most promising attempt:

```
for i in /home/directory/*.spart; do 
    $i > $i/${i: /$.*\.}_sort.txt; done
```

`/$` to match the last / of the line
`.*` match everything after the last /
`\.` match the dot

Comment: Please update your question post and add a desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are glob patterns, not regular expressions. See perhaps [What are the differences between glob-style patterns and regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-patterns-and-regular-expressions)

Your current code is attempting to run `$i` as a command and redirect its output to another file. I'm guessing you were looking to copy the file instead.

```
for i in /home/directory/*.spart; do 
    cp "$i" "${i%.spart}_sort.txt"
done
```

For your examples, this would produce

```
cp /home/directory/escherichia_coli.spart /home/directory/escherichia_coli_sort.txt
cp /home/directory/pseudomonas_aeruginosa.spart /home/directory/pseudomonas_aeruginosa_sort.txt
cp /home/directory/pseudomonas_fluorescens.spart /home/directory/pseudomonas_fluorescens_sort.txt
cp /home/directory/streptocuccus_agalactiae.spart /home/directory/streptocuccus_agalactiae_sort.txt
```

If you really needed to extract just the base name before `.spart`, the `basename` command does that, though you can also do it with a second [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in Bash itself.

```
for i in /home/directory/*.spart; do 
    base=${i%.spart}
    base=${base##*/}
    echo "$base" should be equivalent to "$(basename "$i" ".spart")"
done
```

The weird stuff after `>` in your attempt does not look like Bash syntax at all; are you sure you are not actually using another shell?