# expand on a regex in bash to obtain filename

Tags: bash

I have files under a common folder which contain numbers as a part of them. I am trying to access these files serially through perl command executed via bash script. When I try to obtain filenames based on serial numbers in filenames it does not work. How can I resolve this.

Example filenames:

```
test_S1_L001.sorted.bam
abc_S2_L001.sorted.bam
cdf_S3_L001.sorted.bam
```

I am trying to extract individual filenames using following command in bash

```
script.pl $mapFolder/*S{$id}_L001.sorted.bam
```

Where, $id is numbers after S e.g 1, 2 ,3 provided from the bash script.

```
mainScript.sh 1
mainScript.sh 2
mainScript.sh 3
```

However this command is giving me error below

```
failed to open "mapFolder/*S1_L001.sorted.bam" for reading: No such file or directory
```

It should ideally take full file name for the perl script as

```
script.pl mapFolder/test_S1_L001.sorted.bam
```

Comment: Are you sure `mapFolder` is a subdirectory of your current directory? Try setting `$mapFolder` to an absolute path.

Comment: Yes I have set mapFolder to an absolute path.

Comment: Then it should work. The wildcard should be expanded if there are any matching files.

Comment: If `id` = 1, then `{$id}` becomes `{1}` not `1`

Comment: maybe you meant `${id}` ? Good luck.

Comment: Regarding "expand on a regex..." - shells don't use regexps to find files, they use globbing patterns. Those look and function a bit like regexps, but they have their own syntax and semantics and definitely are not regexps.

Comment: I find the title of your question confusing, since there is no regex anywhere in your posting. Aside from this, the error message comes from your Perl program, and if you claim that the file indeed is there, you better provide a minimal Perl example program, which shows how you open the file.

Comment: Not also that `{$id}` does not make sense. bash does not perform brace expansion, unless there is at least one comma inside the brace (such as in `{$id1,$id2}`. In your case, if `id` is, say, `1`, `{$id}` would expand to `{1}`. You can catch this type of error if you, during debugging of your script, turn on tracing with `set -x`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `script.pl $mapFolder/*S${id}*_L001.sorted.bam` which seems to work.

Comment: This just a typo, then, putting the `$` in the wrong place? Or was there anything else to it? (Questions caused by typographic errors are categorically off-topic).

Comment: (btw, there's no regex in this code at all; what you have here is a glob expression, not a regex)

Comment: There is a wild card * before and after from *S${id} to *S${id}*

Comment: Having a wild card does not make it a regexp. It's a globbing pattern. See [what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-patterns-and-regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-patterns-and-regular-expressions) and google for other definitions/examples.

Comment: In a regexp, `*` is not a wildcard but instead a modifier that says "zero or more of the immediately prior token". So if this _were_ regex syntax, it wouldn't do what you intend; it's only glob syntax where `*` is a wildcard. (If you've seen people write `.*`, that's the regex equivalent to the glob `*`: the `.` means "one character that can be anything", and the `*` modifies it to "zero or more characters that can be anything")