# Pattern match repeat of character class in pure bash

Tags: bash

I want to match the GNU Screen name out of `$STY`. In a Screen `STY=1234.screen-name`.

To cut off the first digit we can use GNU Bash's pattern matching like

```
echo ${STY#[0-9]}
# => 234.screen-name
```

But I can't figure out the "repeat character class" character is. In Perl regexp this character is `*` so the expression would be `[0-9]*` to match zero or more characters of the class `0-9`.

Comment: The patterns used in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) are glob patterns, not regular expressions. There is no repetition operator in globs. Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-patterns-and-regular-expressions

Comment: How about using regex matching?

Comment: Bash supports extended pattern matching that adds (among other things)  `+(pattern-list)` to match one or more occurrences of given patterns.  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways to go about this.

### Sidestepping the issue

We can either avoid matching a specific character class by removing anything up to the dot character instead.

```
echo ${STY#*.}
# => screen-name
```

### Enabling extglobs

Or we can enable extglobs, which enables globs of character classes if I understand correctly.

```
echo ${STY##+([0-9]).}
# => screen-name
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash has got built-in support for matching regular expressions.  See [mkelement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924143/4154375) to [How do I use a regex in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919103/4154375).  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code snippet demonstrates one possible way to use it:

```
[[ $STY =~ ^[[:digit:]]+\.(.*)$ ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` to print the screen name.